# Rails can't connect to external mysql server despite Privileges

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails

I run rails on my local dev environment but the mysql instance is on a separate server.

When trying to open a page in the app I get this error:

`Access denied for user 'username'@'myhostname.lan' (using password: YES)`

When I ssh into the server running mysql and run this command `SELECT Host from mysql.user WHERE User='username';` I get the following:

```
+---------------------+
| Host                |
+---------------------+
| %                   |
| myhostname.lan      |
| localhost           |
+---------------------+
```

All of these entries were created with `GRANT ALL PRIVIELEGES ON dbname.* TO ...`

So why can I not connect given that both the any-host wildcard % is in the list as well as the hostname I try to connect from specifically?

Comment: Is password the same on all three entries? (just compare hashes)

Comment: Indeed you were correct. When I granted the permissions I didn't put the `IDENTIFIED BY 'xxx'` part in so PW was empty.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Despite having same usernames these users are different for mysql.
Check that the password is set on all user entries and is what you expect it to be.

You can compare `authentication_string`s in `mysql.user`.